# Issues Querying XML with Namespace

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I am attempting to consume a Rest service that returns an XML response.  I have successfully made the get request, my problem is processing the response.  The response includes a namespace that seems to be messing up my linq query.  I have tried almost everything I can think of userNames always comes up empty.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and could possibly save my sanity.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tsResponse xmlns="http://tableausoftware.com/api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableausoftware.com/api http://tableausoftware.com/api/ts-api-2.0.xsd">
  <users>
    <user id="c9274ce9-0daa-4aad-9bd2-3b1d6d402119" name="_DevITTemplate" role="Unlicensed" publish="false" contentAdmin="false" lastLogin="" externalAuthUserId=""/>
```

```
string usersList =
request.DownloadString("http://bshagena-sandbox/api/2.0/sites/b4126fe9-d7ee-4083-88f9-                     a5eea1f40416/users/");  
request.Dispose();

XDocument xd;
XElement users;
XNamespace ns = "http://tableausoftware.com/api";

xd = XDocument.Parse(usersList);
users = xd.Root.Elements().First();

var userNames = from a in users.Descendants(ns +"users")
             select    (string)a.Attribute("name").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and it seemed to work. Sorry for all the comments. I am sure this is not the most efficient way to do this. I hope this helps someone else losing their mind over the same issue.

```
// Sends get request and stores response as a string
string usersList =
request.DownloadString("http://<serverName>/api/2.0/sites/b4126fe9-d7ee-4083-88f9-a5eea1f40416/users/");  
// declares an XML document object 
XDocument xd;
// Declares and XML element object
XElement users;
// Declares a stupid XML namespace object 
XNamespace ns = "http://tableausoftware.com/api";
// Sets document to value of string 
xd = XDocument.Parse(usersList);
// Sets the element to value of the first node of the xml document
users = xd.Root.Elements().First();
// Creates an array and queries elements based on attribute of name
var userNames = from a in users.Elements(ns + "user")
             select    (string)a.Attribute("name").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is your `user` element which contains attribute `name`,  not the `names` wrapper element. Adjust your xpath accordingly: (Your use of the `XNamespace` is fine)

```
var userNames = from a in users.Descendants(ns + "user")
                select a.Attribute("name").Value;
```

Minor - `Attribute.Value` is [already a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.value(v=vs.110).aspx) - no need to cast it :)